# How to open React Material-UI modal and populate with Ajax call upon clicking button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Tried to search for a similar question but couldn't find any, apologies if I missed one. I am using React Material-UI to create a simple web application. I have an XGrid which lists a number of products and various statistics over a user-selected date range. Each row has a button that the user can click. The idea is that, upon clicking the button, the application calls an API to get relevant information about the product in that row. I would like the info returned from the API to be displayed on a Material-UI modal.

I am getting stuck on how to pass the information from the API to the Modal component and display it. I have a simple example in the code below that is close to what I want to accomplish.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { Button, Modal, Typography, Box } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button
        variant="outlined"
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => {
          setOpen(true);
          (async () => {
            let response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
            let apiCall = await response.json();
            let grouped_data = JSON.parse(apiCall.data);
          })();
        }}
      >
        Click Here
      </Button>
      <Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Box>
          <Typography>Random Text</Typography>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this example, I isolated the code into one single App.js on codesandbox. However, in practice I would have the Button and Modal combined into a separate component file with the API URL passed as a prop to the component. I also used JSONPlaceholder instead of my actual API. Currently, the button displays a modal which says "Random Text". However, I would like it to display the information retrieved using the fetch call.

Also, the table will have thousands of rows so I would like to avoid calling the API until the user actually clicks the button. That way I don't overload the server with thousands of separate API calls every time someone loads the page. I appreciate any help anyone could provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better to create a variable to hold the information retrieved from the api, and a common function which would be called from the button click. Something like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { Button, Modal, Typography, Box } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setData(null);
  };

  const getData = async (someID) => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${someID}`
      );
      let apiCall = await response.json();
      let grouped_data = JSON.parse(apiCall.data);
      setOpen(true);
      setData(grouped_data);
    } catch (error) {
      //Handle errors
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button
        variant="outlined"
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => {
          getData(someID);
        }}
      >
        Click Here
      </Button>
      <Modal open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <Box>
          <Typography>{data ? data.some_property : ''}</Typography>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response Kieran, very clever solution. The only problem I'm having is that using this solution in e.g. codesandbox, the modal doesn't pop open when I click the button. Not sure if it's something to do with on my end, but I think it's because setOpen and setData are being set in an async function. Any advice on how to handle this?

Comment: Do you have a link to the codesandbox

Comment: Unfortunately I don't as I don't have an account. Just about to leave work for lunch, so I will set one up afterwards and place a link in this comment. Otherwise, all I did was start a React codesandbox, added @material-ui/core as a dependency, and then copied and pasted your code (and changed getData(someID) to getData(1), also tried getData("1")).

Comment: Try this one to test:
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-babycat-i0bdd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ok that link works with the hardcoded value for grouped_data. But when I try to switch to making an API call it doesn't work anymore. Not sure what's happening.

Comment: Nevermind I just had to adjust how I was handling the JSON payload. Adapted your method into the project I'm working on and it works perfectly. Really appreciate your help and I will mark your response as the accepted answer. Have a nice day!